# how to use condition in 2 tables using with relation in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have two tables name is courses and admissions. Now i want to set if user purchase the course then show admitted else show course price. please check the below code:

```
 $courses = Course::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
 $admission = Admission::where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)->first() ?: app(Admission::class);            
                
 return view('Backend.Student.courses', compact('courses', 'admission'));
```

here is my condition in blade file:

```
@if( $course->id == $admission->courses_id )
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><h5 class="p-0 m-0 text-white"> {{ __('Admitted') }}</h5></a>
    </li>
    @if( !empty($admission->status == 'active') )
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="{{ route('access.course', $course->slug) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><h5 class="p-0 m-0 text-white"> {{ __('Continue Course') }}</h5></a>
    </li>
    @endif
    @else
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="{{ route('purchase.course', $course->slug) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><h5 class="p-0 m-0 text-white"> {{ __('Admission Now') }}</h5></a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">{{ __('Price') }}: ৳{{ number_format( $course->price , 0 , '.' , ',' ) }} BDT</li>
@endif
```

This course is working but its showing only one course. When same user purchage multiple course it will show only one course is admitted. But i want if a user purchases multiple courses it should be shown admitted each course. Sorry for my bad english and thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching just the **first** record for admissions, hence there will be only one record.

To get all `Admission` records for the currently logged in user

```php
$courses = Course::latest('id')->get();
$admissions = Admission::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

return view('Backend.Student.courses', compact('courses', 'admissions'));
```

In blade view, you loop over the user's admissions

```php
@foreach($courses as $course)
    {{-- If the user has purchased course --}}
    @if(in_array($course->id, $admissions->pluck('course_id')->toArray())
        @foreach($admissions as $admission)
            {{-- If the course is active --}}
            @if($admission->course_id === $course->id && $admission->status === 'active')
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="{{ route('access.course', $course->slug) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><h5 class="p-0 m-0 text-white"> {{ __('Continue Course') }}</h5></a>
                </li>
            @elseif($admission->course_id === $course->id && $admission->status !== 'active')
               {{-- If the course is not active --}}
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><h5 class="p-0 m-0 text-white"> {{ __('Admitted') }}</h5></a>
                </li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @else        
        {{-- User has not purchased the course --}}
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a href="{{ route('purchase.course', $course->slug) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><h5 class="p-0 m-0 text-white"> {{ __('Admission Now') }}</h5></a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">{{ __('Price') }}: ৳{{ number_format( $course->price , 0 , '.' , ',' ) }} BDT</li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're correct thanks for your comment, but when i applied your code i see its working but admitted text coming multiple time each course, can you take a look my screenshot : https://prnt.sc/F6rP6Zs0Ugnz
I will also going to mark your answer, thanks.

Comment: @HappyArif Have updated answer, please check and see if the issue of duplicate links is resolved